# How to delete data using join in yii2

Tags: yii2

I am using following query for delete all corresponding data to relate on given id My code:

```
  public function actionDeletebyajax() 

  {
  $pid = $_POST['id'];   
  if($pid) {
        $this->findModel($pid)->delete();
        Profile::deleteAll('user_id ='.$pid);
        UserLoyalty::deleteAll('store_id ='.$pid);
        Workorderpopup::deleteAll('workorder_id ='.$pid); 
        Deal::deleteAll('workorder_id ='.$pid); 
        WorkorderCategory::deleteAll('workorder_id ='.$pid);
        store::deleteAll('owner ='.$pid);
        workorders::deleteAll('workorder_id ='.$pid); 
       echo $pid; exit;
 }
 }
```

But here What i want `Workorderpopup` has a child table `Workorderpopup_child` i want delete all child record to but child table has no any relation with `$pid` Is there Any way to delete child's records too ?

Comment: but it has a relation with `Workorderpopup`. you can find and delete those then delete `Workorderpopup`.

Comment: define relation on cascade delete in your db

Comment: Or define triggers methods like beforeDelete()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that relation is `workorderpopup_child.workorderpopup_id` -> `workorderpopup.id`.

It could be something like this

**Cascade delete by IN condition**

```
$workorderpopups = Workorderpopup::find()
    ->select('id')
    ->where(['workorder_id' => $pid])
    ->asArray()->all();

Workorderpopup_child::deleteAll(['in', 'workorderpopup_id', array_values($workorderpopups)]);
```

Or like this:

**Cascade delete by relation unlinking**

```
$workorderpopups = Workorderpopup::find()
    ->select('id')
    ->where(['workorder_id' => $pid])
    ->asArray()->all();

foreach ($workorderpopups as $workorderpopup) {
    $workorderpopup->delete();
}
```

and then override your `Workorderpopup->delete()` as follows

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function delete()
{
    $this->unlinkAll('workorderpopup_child', true);        

    return parent::delete();
}
```

and make sure you have corresponding relation `workorderpopup_child` in `Workorderpopup` class:

```
/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getWorkorderpopup_child()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Workorderpopup_child::className(), ['workorderpopup_id' => 'id']);
}
```

p.s. i haven't tested the code above, so here can be some mistakes